# Salesforce Oauth 2.0 Authorization screen

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

Using [this guide](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) as a reference, I've created a Remote Access application entry in my developer account.
I tried to play around with the Authorization screen that the user should see after navigating to this URL:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[your_client_id]&redirect_uri=[your_redirect_uri]

When I fill in the right values and navigate to the URL, I am not taken to [the screen that I expect to see](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/File%3aOAuthApproval.png), but rather the regular Salesforce login screen.  If I enter credentials & log in, I get redirected to the 'redirect uri' that I set on the Remote Access screen. (i'm using google.com for now).  What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approval screen should appear once the user has logged in, is that not what you see ?

Comment: Good point - I should have explained that.  No, unfortunately.  When I navigate to the URL, I get the login screen.  Whether I enter credentials for my admin user or a separate user I created, the result is the same: I get redirected to the "redirect uri" (in this case i'm using https://www.google.com.  Why is it skipping the auth screen?

Comment: There's an option in your remote access settings that'll cause it to skip the auth screen, make sure you don't have that checked

Comment: I think I see that - "No user approval required for users in this organization".  It was checked - so I unchecked it.  Navigating to the URL, it still redirects me to google.  Maybe the settings are cached for a bit, and I need to try later?

Comment: Ok - it's working now. Under Setup -> My Personal Information -> Personal Information, there is a Remote Access section. Because of other attempts, there was an entry for my application.  I revoked it, then tried the URL again.  This time the auth screen appeared.  Thanks for your help!